# Result set is closed error , with jdbc and postgresql

Tags: postgresql, jdbc, jdbctemplate

When I Run the code, its runs for about 6-7 minutes(here some data is processed) and then I get the error, dataset is closed .

```
    try {
            Connection conn = jdbcTemplate.getDataSource().getConnection();
            conn.setAutoCommit(false);
             st = conn.createStatement(
             );
            st.setFetchSize(500);
            rsSync=  st.executeQuery(StringQUERY);
                while(rsSync.next()){
                    final AcibAcitarnMapper acibAcitarnMapper = new AcibAcitarnMapper();
                    final AcibAcitarnData data = acibAcitarnMapper.mapRow(rsSync,rsSync.getRow());
                    processEachRow(data,null, transactionIdentifier,counter.getAndIncrement()
                            ,request.getConsumers(),"L",0);
                }
      }catch (SQLException s){
            log.error(" ");
      }finally {
            if(rsSync!=null){
                try {
                    rsSync.close();
                    st.close();
                }catch (SQLException s){
                    log.error("");
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre]. Something you're doing is closing the result set, that could mean that possibly you closed it directly, for example somewhere in that `AcibAcitarnData` class, or maybe closed it indirectly by executing another statement on the same `Statement`, or by closing the `Statement` or the `Connection`. Especially the fact that `st` seems to be a field instead of a local variable is highly suspicious.

Comment: I found the issue, there was a timeout set for jdbc query timeout , which was closing the connection! Thank you for your support